Getting an error Using 'receivedResponseAtMillis(): Long' is an error. moved to val in okhttp
I am getting this error after I update okhttp 4.12.0. Here is my below code where I am getting the issue.
fun retrofit2.Response<*>.responseTimeMs(): Long =
    raw().run {
      receivedResponseAtMillis() - sentRequestAtMillis()
}

I have also moved that to val and tried like below. But it is not working.
fun retrofit2.Response<*>.responseTimeMs(): Long {
  val received = raw().receivedResponseAtMillis()
  val sent = raw().sentRequestAtMillis()
  return (received - sent)
}

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.


Using 'receivedResponseAtMillis(): Long' is an error. moved to val

This message is indicating that you have to use val property receivedResponseAtMillis instead of function call receivedResponseAtMillis().
It is not about creating a reference val received = raw().receivedResponseAtMillis() as in your code snippet.
IDEs generally show a quick fix for that error such as Replace with 'receivedResponseAtMillis'
This extension function should work.
fun retrofit2.Response<*>.responseTimeMs(): Long =
    raw().run {
        receivedResponseAtMillis - sentRequestAtMillis
    }

Here is the deprecated annotation for receivedResponseAtMillis()
// OkHttp v4.12.0

@JvmName("-deprecated_receivedResponseAtMillis")
  @Deprecated(
      message = "moved to val",
      replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "receivedResponseAtMillis"),
      level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
  fun receivedResponseAtMillis(): Long = receivedResponseAtMillis

